# Swift: CollectionViewCell did not appear on the UICollectionViewController bug created programatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am a beginner for swift.
And I want to make the collectionview called from tableviewcell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    let detailColorView = ColorCollectionView(collectionViewLayout: layout)

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        detailColorView.bkColor = UIColor.redColor()
    case 1:
        detailColorView.bkColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    case 2:
        detailColorView.bkColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    default:
        detailColorView.bkColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailColorView)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailColorView, animated: true)
}
```

And here is the collectionviewController created programmatically.

```
    import UIKit

    private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

    class ColorCollectionView: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var bkColor: UIColor!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Select a color"
    if bkColor != nil{
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = bkColor
    }else{
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }


    self.collectionView?.registerClass(ColorCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ColorCell

    return cell
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }

}
class ColorCell: UICollectionViewCell{
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews()
{
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}




}
```

But after run, when clicking the tableviewcell, the collectionview did appear, but the customized cell did not appear without any bugs or issues.

I want to get be fixed by who has experienced in swift programming.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine but I think that you still need to add `UICollectionViewDataSource` at the top of the class.

`class ColorCollectionView: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, HERE {`

and later add:

```
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

into the `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Thanks, I tried like this, unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Comment: Is there any git repository or link where I can check the code/project? Maybe I can help you to find the mistake but from here I don't see it